# Where do my Windows Command Prompt properties get saved

Tags: windows, properties, cmd, command-prompt, profile

Where do my Windows Command Prompt properties get saved? That is where do my preferences for Font type, Font size, Window Size get saved? You can find these preferences by clicking properties in the popup menu located in the top left corner of the command prompt. Do they get saved to a file or do they get saved to my registry?

Answer (score 4):

They get saved in the registry. You can find out the settings under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console.

Answer (score 0):

Sheham gave me an excellent starting point for the answer: "console settings are stored in: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console" but it's missing some information. I thought I'd share what I found by adding a separate answer.

After having looked around in my registry, I found that Windows stores the settings of many console profiles and not all of them are found in  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console.

On my PC, I found key with Console prefs in them in:

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2631530418-3592711867-1138214343-500\Console]

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2631530418-3592711867-1138214343-1000\Console]

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Console]

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Console]

This may not be the same in another person's pc as I'm guessing windows makes these key names in a random manner. I found mine by doing a search for console and checking if console prefs lay within the key.

Furthermore, I found that shortcuts to the command prompts don't register preferences in the registry but rather in the shortcut itself. I figured that out by changing their prefs, exporting the registry before and after the change and using WinMerge to compare the differences to find that no console related changes occured. It seems that they store their own Command Prompt preferences in the shortcut itself.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is just whichever of the `S-1-5-...` keys are yours.  Each of those keys is the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` for *some* account on the system.

Comment: @natenho I did not accept sheham because it's incomplete and barebones. I'm going to edit it in an attempt to complete it. Should the edit be accepted, I'll accept his answer. If it isn't I will just flag my answer/expansion as the accepted answer.